# Is there a method to map DataRow to object of class

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Is there a method in c# to automaticaly map the `DataRow` results to Object of class, instead of manualy mapping each column to variable ?

For now I have to write this :
I have EntityName column in database table and EntityName is `String` variable in class, I have to write this for each column (`dr` is `DataRow`):

```
if (!dr.IsNull("EntityName"))
    scoring.EntityName = dr["EntityName"].ToString();
```

is there a method to automate this? 
In spring framework this is `BeanPropertyRowMapper()` method.

Comment: So you have a class with properties which have exactly the same name as the column in the DataTable?

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper). It's a simple open-source object mapper for .NET that does this mapping for you.

```
const string Query = "SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE YourColumn = @Param1";

IEnumerable<YourClass> items;
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("connection string..."))
    items = connection.Query<YourClass>(Query, new { Param1 = 1 });
```

There is no built-in way to do this automatically without using a third-party mapper.

Comment: thank you for clearing out that i have to use third party